# Сайт с использование node.js

Tags: node.js

Буквально вчера начал изучать node.js, язык простой, написал небольшой сервер. Теперь уже несколько часов думаю как его запустить не локально, а со своего хостинга. Подскажите как это реализовать? Как связать node.js с моими html/php файлами? Как включить сервак на хостинге? Не кричите за глупые вопросы, я полный ноль в этом, лучше подскажите как сделать

Comment: node.js не надо связывать с php. Вообщем. А чтобы запустить свой собственный сайт на node.js вам нужен хостинг с поддержкой node.js. Или, что еще лучше, VPS/VDS